# css div collapsing order

Tags: html, css

this is the layout I'm working with.  what I'm trying to achieve is that as the window is collapsed I want the div on the right to collapse allowing the inner elements to be pushed down.

my css is as follows:

```
#left-div {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
#right-div {
  display: block;
  float: left;
}
#right-div elements {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

I basically want to achieve what's going on in the last photo without the right div getting moved down first.  any ideas?

Edited to remove pictures as I've come to an answer and I'm not sure if I was supposed to post them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking various stabs at it, appears that `JavaScript`/`jQuery` may be your only solution...

Comment: that's what I thought... I figured I'd check out SO before I started putting together unecessary JS... which now seems necessary hehe.